# Vba .htmlbody long text can't create new line

Tags: html, vba

My macro contains code provided below. I would like to separate it into more then 1 line but every time I try I have Error message

> Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement" , automaticity Quotation mark is added at the end of first line and code breaks.

```
newYou = "<HTML><BODY><font face=""Gill Sans MT""><font size=""3""><font color=""black"">
Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & " <p><u>LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text 
LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text 
LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text
LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text 
LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text
 LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text 
 LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text
 LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text <p></font></font> 
</BODY></HTML>"
```

Comment: You have to escape some quotation signs. Like: `"<HTML><BODY><font face=\"Gill Sans MT\"><font ... "` and so on. Use an editor with syntax highlighting to escaping your string well.

Comment: I can't escape quotation, if I will do it my email won't be formatted as I want.

Comment: What will happen if you replace the double quotation sign, by a single `'`?

Comment: You need to close the <p> tag you can combine the <font> into one single also like `<font size="3" color="red">` you don't have enough font closings either I think.

Comment: Please put text properly inside the code.

Comment: What do you mean? This is just an example. Font closings are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Simply decided to split message so looks like this.

```
msg1 = "<HTML><BODY><font face=""Gill Sans MT""><font size=""3""><font color= ""black"">Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & " <p><u>LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text <p></font></font> </BODY></HTML>"

msg2 = "second part of the message............."
```

and after

```
myItem.HTMLBody = msg1 & msg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the full content, but you get the idea.  This is the type of situation where it's easier to store the text in a worksheet cell (assuming you're using Excel) or read it in from a text file and replace tokens with your variables.

```
newYou = "<HTML><BODY><font face=""Gill Sans MT""><font size=""3"">" & _
    "<font color=""black"">Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & _
     " <p><u>LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text " & _
    " LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG text LONG" & _
    "text <p></font></font> </BODY></HTML>"
```